# construction of orthogonal matrix with given spectrum

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in  (S^1)^n$ where $S^1$ denotes the unit circle in the complex plane. Does there exists an $n \times n$ real orthogonal matrix $M$ whose set of eigen values 'givan' by $A$?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: the determinant (product of the elements of $A$) has to be real. Actually every complex eignevalue must occur as many times as its conjugate. Besides this, there is no restriction on $A$.

Comment: Ya. Got it. thanks.